# Spring oxm getting type cast error near catch statement

Tags: java, spring, oxm

I am getting error near catch statement Error : required java.lang.Throwabe found org.springframework.oxm.XmlMappingException

```
enter code here public void writeObjectToXml(Object object, String filename) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        try {
            marshaller.marshal(object, new StreamResult(fos));
        } catch (XmlMappingException xme) {
        }
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error :: " + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Type casting is not allowed in catch statement argument.